# A and B is similar ⇒ $A^T$ is similar to $B^T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that, if A and B is similar, then $A^T$ is similar to $B^T$.

Attempt: I try to use the defn of similarity, and then the rule to transpose in different order, but get nowhere. This should be simple...

(Note to self: page 92.)

Comment: Yes, using the definition of similarity and taking transposes should be easy.  What does this give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A\sim B\iff\,\exists\;\text{invertible}\;\;P\;\;s.t.\;\;A=P^{-1}BP\iff A^t=\left(P^{-1}BP\right)^t=P^tB^t\left(P^{-1}\right)^t$$

and since $\;\left(P^{-1}\right)^t=\left(P^t\right)^{-1}\;$ we're done

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $A$ and $B$ being similar means that $A=P^{-1}BP$ for some $P$. What happens if you transpose both sides of this equation?

Answer (score 1):

$A$ similar to $B$

=> P with $B = P^{⁻1}AP$

=> P with $B^T = (P^{⁻1}AP)^T$

=> P with $B^T = P^TA^T(P^{⁻1})^T$

=> $Q=(P^{-1})^T$  with $B^T = Q^{⁻1}A^TQ$

=> $A^T$ similar to $B^T$